# Angular autocomplete - replace field with current highlighted selection

Tags: angular, autosuggest, search-suggestion

I'm using the [Angular autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) in a project.

The user can navigate the autocomplete results with arrow-up and arrow-down. However, I would like to make it behave like the google-suggest does; when selecting a value using arrow-up or arrow down, that the input text also changes.

I currently have the `optionSelected` but I need it *before* selection.

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectSuggestion($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let result of (suggestions$ | async)" [value]="result">
        {{ result.suggestion }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

So for example; I type `jag`, the autocomplete might suggest `jaguar`. I navigate to that entry using the arrows and type `car`. The input would ideally contain `jaguar car` by then.

What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

UPDATE:

I can use the `optionActivated`, but then just as I select the first entry, it gets activated and put in the search-input. I don't want that, I want it to get in the searchbox if the user starts typing when an item is still selected.

Comment: It seems that the option highlighted with the keyboard arrows can be _selected_ by the enter key. Isn't that enough? But to specifically answer your question, the the autocomplete has an output called `optionActivated` which seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: As @AlexBiro mentioned, i think you can update the value on navigation with arrow up and down keys. would you mind to share more code you did?

Comment: @AlexBiro replacing the text on optionActivated is not good enough; it just triggers the first option I navigate to.